# Static constant integer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

When declaring a static constant array in my class like that

```
static const int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 999};
```

I get an error like "In-class initializer for static data member of type const int[] requires constexpr specifier". When I make it this way and declare it as

```
static constexpr int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 999};
```

it works. Why is it not possible to declare static constant arrays? What am I missing?

Comment: It is possible to declare static constant arrays. It's just not possible to specify an initializer for them inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a bit of confusion about *declaration* and *definition* / *initialization* in the question.

Before C++11, the definition (which often includes the initialization) of a static member should be done out-of-class, with the exception of static constants of integral or enumeration types. From [Stroustrup's C++ FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#in-class):

> to use in-class initialization syntax, the constant must be a static const of integral or enumeration type initialized by a constant expression

Even in this case, if the definition is required (e.g when taking the address of the static member), it should be defined out-of-class.

C++11 introduces the `constexpr` specifier to signal compile time initialization, and allows static members to be initialized in-class if declared `constexpr` (check  *Constant static members* section in the reference of [`static`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)).  It also allows [in-class](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) initialization of non-static members but with a wider meaning.